# Must I use annotation @Resource or @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

For example, I have:

```
@Service 
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CarServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<CarMapper,Car> implements CarService {
    .....
}
```

I want to use it in a controller (not the same path with CarService). Must I use annotation like `@Resource` or `@Autowired`? Hasn't Spring taken CarService into control?

I want to figure out if I could use CarService in my controller without writing @Resource or @Autowired.

Comment: If it's part of Controller's constructor, Spring will inject it when creating the Controller. If not, you'll have to `@Autowired` it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However,from my colleague's codes I have read that he has not applied any annotation but just "private final CarService carService", and it works. But as for me, when I do the same(i want to use carService in a different service) , it fails and it shows an NPE on carService.

Comment: How did he configured beans? Did he used XML?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use constructor injection.

Comment: Sure, this would work, but I prefer a more concise method. Thank you.

Comment: Constructor dependency should be preferred when possible, it has several advantages over injecting fields

Answer (score 0):

Your annotations to your service class looks fine, I don't think you need to add anything else.
If you wish to use CarService in your controller though, you do need to field inject it to your controller with @Autowired annotation (Meaning the CarService Impl of course). So I guess it has to be something like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = /aSpecificPath", produces = { })
public class YourController{

    @Autowired
    CarServiceImpl carServiceImpl;

    // rest of the controller code here 
}
```

After injecting your service to your controller, you can use all its methods, alongside the implemented methods from CarService.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However,from my colleague's codes I have read that he has not applied any annotation but just "private final CarService carService", and it works. But as for me, when I do the same(i want to use carService in a different service) , it fails and it shows an NPE on carService.

Comment: I can't say for sure unless I can see your colleague's code. Perhaps he used constructor injection or initialized `carService` somewhere. 
As far as I know, Spring needs to be aware of how to create or obtain this `carService` object. This can be done either by using @Autowired annotation for automatic injection or by initializing it through other means.

Comment: For some reasons, these codes should not be disclosed, and the carService is just an analogy, but your reply helps me to some extent.

Comment: Yeah, thats reasonable. I hope this can help you solve your problem eventually.

Comment: It's funny that I define my CarService under following paths: biz.car.service.CarService(the interface), biz.car.service.impl.CarServiceImpl(the implementation), I use this service in biz.car.service.impl.TrunkServiceImpl by writing 'CarServiceImpl carServiceImpl'  instead of 'CarService carService' or any annotation. It finally works. I guess this would be the matter of path.